# Create a general path for shared file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use file dialogue to pick a file and save it to a folder but I can't figure out how to code a folder path and keep getting "Path not found error"
I'm not at all a coder, so please explain in plain English:)

Below is the piece of code I tried to use but didn't work.

```
ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("UserDomain") & "\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop"
```

Full sub code from comment below:

```
Sub CreateCopyFile(FilePathToCopy As String)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FileToCopy As Scripting.File
    Dim ArchiveFolderPath As String

    'Create a new folder path
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Archive"

    'Create a new folder
    If Not fso.FolderExists(ArchiveFolderPath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder ArchiveFolderPath
    End If

    Set FileToCopy = fso.GetFile(FilePathToCopy)
    FileToCopy.Copy ArchiveFolderPath & "\" & FileToCopy.name
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is what I have that doesnt work.Disclaimer: Codes are NOT mine

Sub CreateCopyFile(FilePathToCopy As String)
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim FileToCopy As Scripting.File
Dim ArchiveFolderPath As String

'Create a new folder path
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Archive"

'Create a new folder
If Not fso.FolderExists(ArchiveFolderPath) Then
fso.CreateFolder ArchiveFolderPath
End If
Set FileToCopy = fso.GetFile(FilePathToCopy)
FileToCopy.Copy ArchiveFolderPath & "\" & FileToCopy.Name

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: I've just tested it and your code (as I've arranged it in your question above) works fine on a local machine with a user that has the correct file/folder permissions. If you have file/folder permission problems, contact the administrator of the computer for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another backslash at the end of the word, "Desktop", and add two backslashes at the very beginning of the path. Like so:

```
ArchiveFolderPath = "\\" & Environ("UserDomain") & "\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put another `\` at the end of `Desktop` and then make sure that you put the file name after it when you are saving.

So will look like `ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("UserDomain") & "\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\"`

Comment: You need to make sure that any end of folder has a \ at the end of it

Answer (score 0):

Some of what you are looking for is going to depend on the operating system. In Windows 7, there is a Public Desktop that populates all user desktops and has fairly open file permissions. It is located at:

> c:\Users\Public\Desktop

If that is where you want to put things then your code would be one of these,

```
ArchiveFolderPath = "c:\Users\Public\Desktop"
ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("PUBLIC") & "\Desktop"
```

If you wanted to point to the current users desktop then that would be one of these,

```
ArchiveFolderPath = "c:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop"
ArchiveFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
```

The environment variable that you are using (`Environ("USERDOMAIN")) typically points to the computer name in a workgroup environment although it would be different in a structured Active Directory network.

Remember to use environment variables whenever possible to avoid variations in hard-coded paths between system operating versions. An XP machine's user profiles are not in the same place as a Windows 7 or Windows 8 machine.

A quick and easy way to get a list of the environment variables in the current session is to open a command prompt window and type `SET` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It said permission denied